# How does one determine statistical significance between two fits?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Sorry if this question is something very basic, but I am (attempting to) learning data analysis on my own and I haven't seen anything that quite fits what I want to do.  I am working on a personal project to test my understanding, and I seem to be missing something.

I have a dataset where I have a metric that has been measured at different times.  I am trying to see whether the introduction of an intervention had any effect.  My "plan" is to fit the data up until the time of the intervention and compare that to the fit for the whole data.

My question is how to determine if the differences in the fits are significant enough for me to reject the null hypothesis?  Or is there a better way to test if the intervention has had any effect?

Comment: The typically approach in this context is a [regression discontinuity design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_discontinuity_design). You fit the data before the intervention and the data after, and you can test whether the jump at the intervention is statistically significant.

Comment: You could (1) compute the percentage change in the metric between the start of the trial and the time just before intervention. Call this $x_1$. (2) compute the percentage change in the metric from the point of intervention and the end of the trial. Call this $x_2$. Then you can compare the averages of $x_1$ and $x_2$ to gauge any practically significant difference pre and post intervention. Any statistically significant difference could be assessed through a hypothesis test.